# Get the sum of a map in Reactor Mono

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

How do I add up all the results of a Mono/Flux

I have some reactive code where i return a Flux and chain some other functions, I will explain it with some code.

```
return commentService.getAllCommentByIssueId(issueId)
                .map {
                    taggingService.tagging(it.content).map {
                        //Get the count of the returned set and add it up to 
                        //all the other returned map results
                        //So the result should be like
                        //tags in first comment 2, tags in second comment 3
                        //so it should return 5
                    }
```

So I return a Flux, it is a Flux of Comments. I want to map all the comments of this query, to a function where I scan the content of each comment for tags, this is implemented by the `taggingservice.tagging`, that function returns a `Mono<MutableSet<UUID>>` so it returns all the UUIDs which got tagged.
An issue has a x number of comments, I want to sum up all the tags in all comments.

What I want to do is to count up all the tags of each comment of an issue and return it in a StatsModel which consists of `StatsModel(issueId,numberOfTagsInComments)`

I will show you now the tagging function:

(I tested the function, it is working)

```
fun tagging(text:String) : Mono<MutableSet<UUID>> {
        val words = text.split( " ")
                .filter { it.startsWith("@")}
        val matches : MutableSet<UUID> = mutableSetOf()

        return userRepository.findAll().collectList()
                .map { userList ->
                    for(word in words){
                        userList.map {user ->
                            if(user.username == word.substring(1)) {
                                matches.add(user.id!!)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    matches
                }
    }
```

And my CommentRepository, I am using the first function fo this repo.

```
@Repository
interface CommentRepository: ReactiveCrudRepository<CommentModel, UUID> {
    fun findAllByIssueId(issueId: UUID): Flux<CommentModel>
    fun findAllByUserId(userId: UUID): Flux<CommentModel>
}
```

Comment: You should probably use` Flux::reduce` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but like I said, it seems like you want to reduce.

Your question is not clear because you are returning a `Set` from your tagging function but a `Set` only allows unique values so what if the same tag is in a comment twice?

Anyway, assuming you want the total count of unique tags in each comment, you can consider this:

I make a DB (a map) of tags and UUIDs

```
Map<String, UUID> tags;
tags = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"tag1", "tag2"}).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), s->UUID.randomUUID() ));
```

My version of a tagging function:

```
Mono<Set<UUID>> tagging(String string) {
    return Flux.fromArray(text.split(" ")).filter(str->str.startsWith("@")).map(str->str.substring(1)).map(tags::get).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

A function to fetch a `Flux<String>` of comments:

```
Flux<String> getAllComments() {
    return Flux.fromArray(new String[] {"this is @tag1", "and @tag2", "finally @tag1 and @tag2", "unclear @tag1 and @tag1"});
}
```

And some simple logic to sum the size of each `Set`:

```
getAllComments()
    .flatMap(this::tagging)
    .map(Set::size)
    .reduce(Integer::sum)
    .map(StatsModel::new)
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

And assuming `lombok` is your friend

```
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class StatsModel{
    UUID issueId = UUID.randomUUID();
    @NonNull
    Integer count;
}
```

gives me:

```
StatsModel(issueId=a3cf1243-8a89-406c-b0e8-c13a6bdc832c, count=5)
```

The generated UUID is free of charge.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that only one tag counts in one comment and I maybe need to add that my return commentService.getAllCommentByIssueId(issueId) already exists and returns a Flux of comments. I will edit that function in now aswell into the topic

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to state the final goal clearly: you want to get `StatsModel(issueId, numberOfUniqueTagsInComments)`. We can then decompose this into subproblems (I'll change the naming a bit for clarity):

- Get all comments from an issue: `fun getAllComments(issueId): Flux<Comment>`
- Get unique tags from content: `fun uniqueTags(text: String): Mono<Set<UUID>>`
- Merge tags: give a `List<Set<UUID>>`, you can use `reduce` to get a final `Set<UUID>`. Note that for this you don't need to use Reactor, just use regular Kotlin.

Putting all together:

```kotlin
getAllComments(issueId)            // Flux<Comment>
  .flatMap { uniqueTags(it) }      // Flux<Set<UUID>>
  .collectList()                   // Mono<List<Set<UUID>>
  .map { uuidSets ->
    uuidSets
      .reduce { acc, set -> acc + set } // Set<UUID>
      .size()                           // Int
  }
  .map { StatsModel(issueId, it) }
```

Comment: I am getting a type interference error after the reduce